# Are there any plugins or production techniques that can tranform a male voice into a female voice

Tags: sound-effects, timbre

I know how to achieve this with hardware (TC Helicon VoiceLive) but I'm hoping to find a way to manipulate vocal gender in a DAW like Ableton. I'm especially interested in knowing if it's possible to automate this during playback.

Here is an example: these vocals are done by a male: Amon Tobin.

Comment: [Celemony Melodyne](http://www.celemony.com/en/melodyne/what-is-melodyne) can do this.

Comment: Male and female voice are an example of vowel morphing. Tables of vowel morphing frequencies exist for all human types and languages, man woman child, different accents. So the process requires grain resynthesis and filters in some combination. The solutions you find may have some kind of vowel morphing synthesis component to them.

Comment: I'll experiment with that a bit. If nothing else I'll come up with something unique sounding.

Answer (score 1):

You can go and check the IRCAM Tool : TRAX. They are a French Sound Research Center, and they created some pretty powerful plug-ins lately.

http://www.fluxhome.com/products/plug_ins/ircam_trax-v3

Cheers

Ben